# update the name of student in tableB if the rollno in tableA and TableB matches.condition to update - if first row match then update to "FirstStudent"

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I dont know how to create an array and use a for loop in sql .

```
merge 
 into student ta
using student2 tb
   on (tb.rollno= ta.rollno)
when matched
then update 
        set ta.name = 'xyz';
```

I am able to check the equality and update it by a default value'xyz'. I want to create an array and fetch the values from the array and update it accordingly

Comment: Sorry, but I don't quite understand what you have nor what you want. Why do you think you need an array? Could you post test case (CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample data, as well as desired result)?

Comment: If the rollno in row1 of tableA matches roll no of row1 if table B then update name to student1 . If the rollno in row2 of tableA matches roll no of row2 if table B then update name to student2 .

Comment: Which part of "Could you post test case (CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample data, as well as desired result)?" did you not understand?

Comment: CREATE TABLE tableA ( rollno INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT NOT NULL); INSERT INTO students VALUES (1, 'Ram'); INSERT INTO students VALUES (2, 'Raghu'); INSERT INTO students VALUES (3, 'Joe');
CREATE TABLE tableB ( rollno INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT NOT NULL); INSERT INTO students VALUES (1, 'SAN'); INSERT INTO students VALUES (2, 'Liana'); INSERT INTO students VALUES (3, 'James');

Now the expected result : 
 Table B - 
1,student1 
2,student2
3,student3

Comment: Then it's just `update tableb set name = 'student' || to_char(rollno);   `. What do you need TABLEA for? Or an array? Or MERGE (using another table)?

Comment: Ok this works. What if I want to update it as "First student" , "Second student" etc

Comment: Also I need tableA to compare roll no of students with roll no of table b

Comment: Consider this test case 
Table A - 1, ram 2,raghu 4,joel 
Table B - 1, San , 2, Liana 3, James 
Output 
Table B - 1, "First Student" 2,Second Student 3, James

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option: use combination of `TO_CHAR` and `TO_DATE` functions with appropriate format models (convert `ID` to a Julian date, then apply `SPTH` format model to *spell* that number).

Instead of `update`, use `merge` as it'll affect only matching rows.

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from tablea;

        ID NAME
---------- -----
         1 ram
         2 raghu
         4 joel

SQL> select * from tableb;

        ID NAME
---------- --------------------
         1 san
         2 liana
         3 james
```

Merge:

```
SQL> merge into tableb b
  2    using tablea a
  3    on (a.id = b.id)
  4    when matched then update set
  5      b.name = to_char(to_date(b.id, 'J'), 'jspth') || ' student';

2 rows merged.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from tableb;

        ID NAME
---------- --------------------
         1 first student
         2 second student
         3 james

SQL>
```

---

What does right hand side of line #5 do:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select to_date(1, 'J') from dual;

TO_DATE(1,
----------
01.01.4712

SQL> select to_char(to_date(1, 'J'), 'jspth') from dual;

TO_CH
-----
first

SQL>
```

Read about [format models](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00216).

---

What if ID was 1008? Nothing:

```
SQL> select to_char(to_date(1008, 'J'), 'jspth') from dual;

TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(100
-------------------
one thousand eighth

SQL>
```

Comment: Can you please explain or give some link where I can understand this ?  b.name = to_char(to_date(b.id, 'J'), 'jspth') || ' student';

Comment: I am getting this error "date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Comment: Have a look at edited answer for some more info. As of the error you got, I don't know what you did nor which data you used. As you can see, there was no error for sample data you posted and code I wrote.

Comment: Why do you think that you should modify it? ID value is irrelevant. See yet another edit.

Comment: If my ID is 9 digit number in that case  what should be the line no 5 ?

Comment: Also  I have some modification in the question . Shall I ask here only?

Comment: I answered all questions you had, with sample data you posted. If question has changed, ask a new question. This one is done (as far as I'm concerned).